# Hiredis dependency not resolving

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild, centos6.5, hiredis

Please help me understand where rpm looks for libhiredis. Software could easy find rest of the dependencies like libev etc, which i installed using yum. For hiredis i used regular make && make install as yum had really old package. This is the only difference.

CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

```
I have created link to hiredis under every possible location i knew - 
/lib,
/lib64,
/usr/lib,
/usr/lib64

/usr/local/lib contains the file

yum install /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Examining /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
Marking /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.excellmedia.net
* epel: epel.mirror.srv.co.ge
* extras: centos.excellmedia.net
* updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package snitest.x86_64 0:0.1.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libhiredis.so.0.12()(64bit) for package: snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (/snitest-0.1.0-1.el6.x86_64)
       Requires: libhiredis.so.0.12()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

rpm/yum **cannot** find software you installed manually. It doesn't work that way. You get to use the package or build your own if you want this to work. There's also no guarantee that the packaged software will even **work** with a newer version of the hiredis library in the first place.